# Node.js POST request without redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, redirect

Originally, my routes would redirect the user to the page they submitted the request. However, this sends them back to the top of the page.

I implemented AJAX to submit the request, but what do I write in the route? I was originally using res.redirect, but switched wherever it said `res.redirect` to `return`, thinking that that would work, however my page just gets stuck in a process and after a minute or so, the page errors.

What is the correct way to process a request and then just stop?

How come `return` doesn't work?

Comment: can you add some code please?

Comment: show the Code please

Comment: you need to send some response instead of `return`.. use `res.send()`

Comment: Please shoe the code. Are you using express ?

Answer (score 0):

Use them together like this:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  if (/*<case when you need redirect>*/) {
    return res.redirect('/path/to/redirect');
  } else if (/*<case when you need simple response>*/) {
    return res.send();
  }

  // some other code here
}
```